# How to stop LinkButton from being greyed out by IE when disabled?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is there an easy way to stop LinkButtons from being greyed out in IE when disabled, as it makes them hard to read.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the css styles for disabled link buttons.

See how do do it it [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2005/09/28/132561.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged with "css", I think this answer could be helpful too:

The key concept of styling a link stands toward following steps:

1. You have to declare styles of 4 different condition which are `a:link` , `a:visited` , `a:hover` , `a:active` .
2. You have to be careful about the order. Because it matters. link > visited > hover > active.
3. Eventhough you don't need styling one or more of conditions, nevertheless, style them all.

If you pay attention to these, you may have perfectly styled links.

I hope it helps.