# Stopping a LinkButton from being greyed out when disabled in IE

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to make it so that a LinkButton doesn't get greyed out in IE when Enabled="False". Disabling the postback like they suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176827/disable-the-postback-on-an-asplinkbutton) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686282/how-to-stop-linkbutton-from-being-greyed-out-by-ie-when-disabled) works but doesn't stop the cursor and text colour from changing when you hover over it as if it were a button, like Enabled="False" does.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkBut1" runat="server" CssClass="Tag" Enabled="False" 
            OnClick="LB_Click" Text="Add" />
```

(Using .NET 4 and C#)
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The only thing I can see that leading to is that users will be confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered extending the LinkButton class, overwriting the Rend method and doing something like:

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!this.enabled)
          ...write an html span that looks like a link or something ...
        else
          base.Render(writer);
    }
```